# Jquery change Contenteditable attr IE

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, attr

I have the following short code to create a div when button is clicked, inside the div is a span tag with contenteditable="false". When span is doubled clicked, it should set and change the contenteditable attribute from false to true, so text can be made editable on dblclick.  Check the example at http://jsfiddle.net/dtxhe/

This is working in firefox, chrome and ie8, but not IE7 or quirks mode. 
Any ideas. How can i fix this.

Comment: @alex You should try a different event, like single click... I've heard of double click causing problems in IE7. That's just an idea--not sure what else I can say.

Comment: @alex On jsFiddle, place the JavaScript code inside the JavaScript box. That'll make your demo more readable.

Comment: dblclick works fine in ie. Even if you change it to click, it still doesn't work. I clueless to what could be causing this.

Comment: @alex I cleaned up your demo. http://jsfiddle.net/dtxhe/3/

Comment: Thanks @Sime. It's only few lines of code. I didn't bother with the jsfiddle cleanup.

Comment: Try setting it to .attr('contenteditable','contenteditable'); instead of the boolean true. Booleans dont work too hot as attributes. :)

Comment: Thanks Paul. But that doesn't work. I put an alert after double click  to check the boolean value, and i see it is being set to true after dblclick but it's just not creating an editable area in IE7 and quirksmode. I was hoping you had a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you hadn't already figured this one out the answer I believe is the difference between "contenteditable" and "contentEditable" for the attribute name. IE7 is picky.